# "Date" giving compiler error "Can't find project or library" (VB6)

Tags: vb6, visual-studio-2003, vb5

I have some VB6 code that I need to port to VB.NET or C# or F#.

First of all, I try to compile it, and it doesn't succeed. When I press F5, a dialog box is opened that tells me "Can't find project or library" while highlighting the word "Date" in the following if condition:

```
Dim HourAux As Date
...
If (HourAux > CDate (Date & " " & Question(2).Text) Then
...
End if
```

So, what I'm wondering is:

1. Have I been given code that really doesn't compile and needs to be fixed?
2. Or am I missing something really obvious like a reference to a library or something?
3. Or is it that I'm trying to compile VB5 code with a VisualStudio (6.0) that is for VB6?

Thanks in advance for any comments or help.

Comment: The error message you got suggests that the compiler wasn't installed incorrectly and can't find the resource file that contains the string "'Date' is a type and cannot be used as an expression."  You can't.  Your VS version is way too old to tell you where to look.  It may be worn out.  Updating from a 15 year old compiler to a 10 year old compiler is not productive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I was simply missing a reference that my project requires, and VisualStudio (or the VB compiler) is giving a very misleading error.

I was missing the reference "Microsoft Excel 8.0 Object Library", and to get it I had to install Microsoft Office, obviously. You find the references of your project by going to the menu Project -> References... in VS main menu.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I have to replace "date" with "datetime.date"
I also had to replace "right", "left", "mid", "len" , "instr", "revstr" with:

```
strings.right
strings.left
strings.mid
strings.len
strings.instr
```

Every VBA command I had to add the class as a precedent, for it to work.